No module named qiskit_ibm_runtime
It is showing No module named "qiskit_ibm_runtime" when I try to import QiskitRuntimeService from it in jupyter notebook.
I have installed it using pip install qiskit-ibm-runtime.
I can see the package is installed via pip list 
that setuptools is also installed there.
what should I do? Please help me,
Thank you.

You aren't telling us where you are running the install command or the pip list. Jupyter is very particular about environments and so just installing to your system isn't necessarily enough. In the notebook where you are trying to import, did you run %pip list and see what was available to the running kernel backing the active notebook? Similarly, you may be able to then run %pip install qiskit-ibm-runtime in a new cell above the when you want to execute the import statement from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService. You may need to restart even more than the kernel ...

 for things to fully take effect after running the magic install command. For complex installs, just restarting the kernel isn't enough. You want to quite Jupyter and the browser and restart everything to be sure, before trying the import statement in the notebook. See more about the modern magic %pip install & %pip list commands for running inside active notebooks to ensure the actions occur in the environment the kernel uses here.
